# How to set UISegmentedControl Background image through storyboard?

Tags: ios, uiimage, uisegmentedcontrol

in iOS Application, my current UISegmented Control for male and female looks like this :

[image]

Now I want to change background image of these segments.So I changed in storyboard as below :

```
 For Segment 0:
```

[image]

```
 For Segment 1:
```

[image]

```
 After this changes,I got the result as below :
```

[image]

Why these images are overlapped with each other ? any specific reason or is these segments size is according to image size? How can I set background image of segments without affecting size of segments (Full image should be displayed in the background of segment rather than overlapping)?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I found using UISegmentedControl was just a pain when using images . Perhaps you can create your own UIView subclass to get maximum flexibility - That’s what I ended up doing.

Comment: @SEG : But then we can not get features of segmented control when we use our own UIView subclass.

Comment: Yeah, you'd need to recreate that. Create a setup method where you pass your images and strings. In that method add your required number of UIButton's (set the corresponding images and/or strings), set a tag to each UIButton to be able to know which button was pressed. In the touch-up-inside handler of the buttons, call a delegate method or block. It's not that hard to recreate the UISegmentedControl...

Answer (score 5):

Try to make customization in code like this.

```
[self.segmentedControl setDividerImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"style_segmented_control_delimiter.png"]
                     forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected
                       rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
                              barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

  [self.segmentedControl setDividerImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"style_segmented_control_delimiter.png"]
                     forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
                       rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
                              barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

  [self.segmentedControl setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"style_segmented_control_normal_mid.png"]
                                   forState:UIControlStateNormal
                                 barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

  [self.segmentedControl setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"style_segmented_control_press_mid.png"]
                                   forState:UIControlStateSelected
                                 barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for overlapping of images is size of the image aacording to segment size.

- Set the image size properly . For example if you have two segments ,set the image of size (totoalWidthOfSeg/2).
- There might some gap may appear between segments for that we have to set devider image also